# как получить соседние символы?

Tags: python

Как получить 10 символов слева и 10 символов справа, от строки?
К примеру есть строка "Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности обеспечивает широкому **кругу** (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений."
К примеру надо найти слово: "кругу" и 10 символов слева и справа
слева это " широкому "
справа это " (специали"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
text = "Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений."

word = "кругу"
ind = text.find(word)

text[ind-10: ind+len(word)+10]
```

Comment: @ КириллМалышев спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = "Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений."
res = re.findall(r".{10}кругу.{10}", s)[0]
start10 = res[:10]
end10 = res[-10:]
print(start10)
print(end10)
```

https://ideone.com/QZL3EX

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений."
word = "кругу"
f = string.find(word)
print("left = " + string[f-10:f+0])
print("right = " + string[f+len(word):f+len(word)+10])
```

Comment: `f + 0 == f` !)